# Meta viewport has no effect completely in phone and chrome device mode

Tags: python, html, css

hi guys I am using html but when i add the folowing `<meta>` element in the head , the Viewport wont change on the phone and chrome device mode:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title>phone</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body style="background-image: url('space.jpg')">
     <img src="https://www.drgoulu.com/wp-content/uploads/HLIC/c2281c83670e31d8aaab7cb642b824db.png">
     <p>Python est un langage de programmation objet, multi-paradigme et multiplateformes. Il favorise la programmation impérative structurée, fonctionnelle et orientée objet. Wikipédia</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to put `width: 100%` in `img` tag

```
# style.css

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    # or simple width
    # width: 100%;
}
```

or direct in `img` tag

```
<img style="width: 100%" src="https://www.drgoulu.com/wp-content/uploads/HLIC/c2281c83670e31d8aaab7cb642b824db.png">
```

Comment: the way is worked for the image but the width of the background-image is not changed .

Comment: put for background image also 100%